# Recently added friends

Tags: facebook

I added an old friend and now he doesn't show on the right side of profile by recently added but he is still added. Why did he mysteriously move from that list?

Comment: Can't tell for sure, but this might have something to do with his privacy settings.

Comment: Does the friend appear in the activity log? URL: `https://www.facebook.com/your-user-name/allactivity`